# Diagrama E/R en SQL

Tags: sql, relaciones, modelorelacional

Hola tengo una duda acerca del desarrollo de un Diagrama Entidad Relación. No se cual de las siguientes 3 relaciones es la correcta para la siguiente tabla y especificación de requisitos. Las 3 opciones creo que terminan en el mismo Esquema Relacional (Diseño Fisico de datos) es decir que las tablas resultantes y sus atributos no cambian... ¿O si?

Tenemos `Contratistas`, `Empleados` y `Vehiculos`.

- Un **Contratista** puede tener N **Vehiculos** en su flota.
- Un **Empleado** puede tener asignados N **vehiculos**. *(Ej. Una excavadora y un vehiculo de empresa).*
- Un **Vehiculo** puede pertenecer a 1 unico **Empleado**. *(Se puede cambiar dicho empleado a través de una funcion `changeDriver()`)*.
- Un **Contratista** puede tener N **Empleados**. Y un **Empleado** puede pertenecer unicamente a 1 unico **Contratista**.

¿Que analisis realizar para llegar a la conclusión adecuada a pesar de que ambos van a generar el mismo Diseño Físico? (La siguiente tabla es la tabla **Vehiculos**, Omito **Contratistas** que es unicamente la `PK` y sus `atributos` y **Empleados** que es su `PK`, la `FK del Contratista` y sus `atributos`)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

> OPCION 1 | **Two 1-N**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> OPCION 2 | **N-M**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> OPCION 3 | **N-M-P**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Un vehiculo puede ser asignado a varios empleados?  De todas formas usa la primera opcion

Comment: ¿Que analisis realizar para llegar a la conclusión adecuada a pesar de que ambos van a generar el mismo Diseño Físico? Esa es la pregunta. Gracias de todos formas. He editado la pregunta con la relación que faltaba.

Comment: La pregunta pareciera basada en opiniones

Comment: Si no me equivoco... dada una especificación de requisitos dicho Diagrama E/R y sus dependencias funcionales responden a principios matemáticos que muy dificilmente puedan estar basados en opiniones. ¿Que módelo es el adecuado? ¿Por que? Gracias.

Comment: Realmente te estas equivocando , solo un diseño esta bien , y los tres no generan los mismos esquemas. Usa la opcion 1. La opcion dos pones vehiculo como un enlace no como una entidad ¿¿?¿?¿?¿En serio?. Y en la opcion tres haces una ternaria e incluyes que un vehiculo pueda ser de varios contratistas. En que te basas para pensar que tres diseños totalmente diferentes te generaran el mismo esquema de BBDD?

Comment: El 3 no cierto. Pero si que se genera el mismo esquema para los 1 y 2 ¿cierto? En una N-M la unión entre ambas genera una nueva tabla con su propio PK y un FK para cada una de las anteriores. Que es lo mismo que genera la Opcion 1 como se ve en la imagen que he subido. Esta bien me quedo con el primer Modelo. Pero creo que si imagen 1 e imagen 2 generan el mismo esquema relacional en una BBDD - 3 tablas con sus PK y vehiculos con las FK de las anteriores.